# how assign date into DatePicker Fabric-react with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, web-scraping, ui-automation, cypress

I think my question is very specific, I have searched [Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress) issues section but they don't use [office-ui-fabric-react](http://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/oufr/6.206.0/#/) accurately. However, it helped me find an approximate solution.

**The problem**
I need to assign a date to [datePicker](http://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/oufr/6.206.0/#/examples/datepicker). but it can't be done using `cy.get('select').type('value')`. Because the Fabric component defaults the input field to readonly.

then it is necessary to click on the calendar that is displayed and locate the options as appropriate. therein lies the second problem.

Fabric shows the current year field and its respective months as can be seen in the image.
[image]

The complexity is when trying to find different years from the current one.

---

I did my best to use fairly generic selectors from this library. I hope you can understand my situation and thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a solution as acceptable as possible. it worked quite well for me. But I would like to find a shorter, simpler, more maintainable method.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('datePicker', (date = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-US')) => {
    const months          = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    const shortMonths     = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    const currentYear     = new Date().getFullYear();

    const arDate      = date.split('/');
    let dateYear        = arDate[2];
    let dateDay         = arDate[1];
    let dateMonth       = arDate[0];
    let exactlyDecade   = true;
    let yearDecade      = currentYear;


    /*  Open popup with calendar */
    cy.get('#datePicker_EffectiveDateFrom-label').should('be.visible').click();

    /*  Evaluate to year */
    if(dateYear != currentYear){

        /* click expand decade */
        cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-currentYear').should('be.visible').click();

        /* Search exactly year */
        while(exactlyDecade){
            cy.log(yearDecade);

            //⬆ click Up arrow
            if(dateYear<currentYear){
                yearDecade = yearDecade - 12;
                cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-prevDecade').should('be.visible').click();
            }

            // ⬇ click Down array
            else{
                yearDecade = yearDecade + 12;
                cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-nextDecade').should('be.visible').click();
            }

            if(dateYear >= yearDecade){
                cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-yearOption').should('be.visible').contains(`${dateYear}`).click();
                exactlyDecade = false;
            }
        }
        /*  Select the month (note that the selector changes if you have searched for the year) */
        if(exactlyDecade){
            cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-monthPicker').should('be.visible').contains(shortMonths[dateMonth-1]).click();
        }else{
            cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-monthOption').should('be.visible').contains(shortMonths[dateMonth-1]).click();

        }
        /* finally we select the day */
        cy.get('.ms-DatePicker-table').should('be.visible').find(`[aria-label="${months[dateMonth-1]} ${Number(dateDay)}, ${dateYear}"]`).click();
    }

});
```